# gcloud functions call giving an error for background

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am testing node js app using mocha and assert.

Get sample code from [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/helloworld)

I deploy helloBackground function in local and also in gcloud succesfullly

then I try to execute mocha test case.

also tried all way to call gcloud functions describe [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/wiki/Calling-functions#calling-background-functions)

Then execute below command in CMD

`functions call helloBackground --data '{\"name\": \"John\"}'`

This should return "Hello John!" in command prompt.

but I receive an error as

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Please let me know how to pass proper data in CMD to test.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your error message, it is most likely caused by the trigger argument you used when you deployed the app. The `helloBackground` function is a Background Function, and instead of --trigger-http, you should use a background function trigger.

For example: `$ gcloud functions deploy helloBackground --runtime nodejs6 --trigger-resource you_bucket_name --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize`

You would need to create an empty .txt file in the same directory of your app and upload it to Cloud Storage

```
$ gsutil cp test.txt gs://[ the name of your cloud storage bucket ]
```

And you can run the app again.

You will find more explanation on the type of functions [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem)
And you can follow this well documented tutorial on Cloud Storage [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage)